# Print (in descending order) the number occurrence in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble figuring out how to find the occurrence of the numbers inside a 2D array. I'm new to java, so I have to do this program without using maps/advanced solutions.

Example:

Given Array (by the user):

[image: an example of the given array above]

Result:

[image: example of the result array above]

This is what I have so far (the method I have trouble figuring out most is freqOccurrence!!!):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i, j;
    int[][] m = readDimension();

    lerMatriz(m);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(m));
    freqOccurrence(m);
}

private static int[][] readDimension() {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Number of rows? ");
    int i = in.nextInt();

    while (i < 1) {
        System.out.println("Please define a valid number of rows. ");
        i = in.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Number of columns? ");
    int j = in.nextInt();

    while (j < 1) {
        System.out.println("Please define a valid number of columns. ");
        j = in.nextInt();
    }

    int[][] m = new int[i][j];
    return m;
}

private static void readMatrix(int[][] m) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nInput integers to save in the array:");

    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print("Element " + i + "," + j + ": ");
            m[i][j] = in.nextInt();
        }
    }
}

private static double freqOccurrence(int[][] m) { //??????????????????

    int num = 0;
    int[][] m2 = new int[][];

    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
            if (m[i] == num) {
                m2[num]++;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate all the help!

Comment: I have to do this without using maps, as I'm still new to java and am only allowed to do this the "hard" way

Comment: make an 2D-array (size = number of distinct element for both dimension, x = element, y = occurrence), then populates it, sort it, and print it

Comment: Are you allowed to sort either?

Comment: "I'm having trouble figuring out" is not specific enough for this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this (assuming you're allowed to use built-in sorting, and that each of the arrays in your array is the same length) is in a few steps:

1. Take all the arrays from your 2D array provided as input and fill a 1D array with all the values therein.
2. Sort the 1D array. This ensures that, when iterating through, the number of times a number is repeated is the number of times it occurs in the entirety of the 2D array.
3. Iterate through the 1D array and get the number of unique values. Use this as the size of the first dimension of the array which will be returned; the second dimension will always be 2 (value, frequency)
4. Iterate through the 1D array, counting how many times any given value appears in succession. Add the value and the number of times this appears to the occurrence array.

Here's the code:

```
private static int[][] getOccurrenceArray(int[][] input)
{
    // create a new 1D array that we'll shove
    // all indices of the 2D array into
    int[] inputCopy = new int[input.length * input[0].length];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < input[0].length; j++) {
            inputCopy[index] = input[i][j];
            index++;
        }
    }

    Arrays.sort(inputCopy);

    // find the number of unique values in the 1D array - this will be the length of 
    //the first dimension of your frequency array
    int uniqueValues = 1;
    int previouslySeen = inputCopy[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < inputCopy.length; i++) {
        // if value at the current index isn't the same as the value
        // at the previous index, we've found a new unique value
        if (inputCopy[i] != previouslySeen) {
            uniqueValues++;
        } 

        previouslySeen = inputCopy[i];
    }

    // create the frequency array
    int[][] frequencyArray = new int[uniqueValues][2];
    previouslySeen = inputCopy[0];
    int frequency = 0;
    index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputCopy.length; i++) {
        // if we haven't reached a new value, increment the frequency
        if (inputCopy[i] == previouslySeen) {
            frequency++;
        }
        // if we've reached a new value, assign the previous totals to
        // the array and reset frequency to 1
        else {
            frequencyArray[index][0] = previouslySeen;
            frequencyArray[index][1] = frequency;
            index++;
            frequency = 1;
        } 

        previouslySeen = inputCopy[i];
    }

    // don't forget to record the last value group
    frequencyArray[frequencyArray.length - 1][0] = previouslySeen;
    frequencyArray[frequencyArray.length - 1][1] = frequency;

    return frequencyArray;
}
```

Some of these features, if you're going to reuse any of the functionality, should be pulled out into different methods (particularly the code to collapse a 2D array into a 1D array, and the one that finds the number of unique items in your sorted 1D array).

Answer (score 0):

You have a give array N rows and M columns.

Let's define result array 2 rows N*M columns (if all the numbers in the inisital array are unique N*M is enough anyway).

Go throuh the initial array (2 loops by rows and columns). For each value call a method

```
updateResult(int[][] result, int theNumber)
```

In the method go throug the result array to find whether the number already present in the results.

If the number is not found just add in the end with frequency 1.

If it's already exist increase the frequency and start reordering. Suppose you find the index of current number is K in the result array. After changing frequency compare with the left cell. If the new frequency is bigger and left neighbour's cell swap them and again check with left neighbour cell. Continue till either left cell has the same frequency of the cell is the leftmost (0 position).